# What is the new Network Admin section?

Tags: network-admin

Previously, in WordPress 3.0, multisites were managed through a Super-Admin section of the administration interface. The 3.1 update seems to have moved the administration of multisites to a new "Network Admin" section, which has a similar layout to the standard WP administration panels, but only contains options related to network administration.

This section, however, seems to be pretty similar to the old Super-Admin section. Has there been any additional network management features added, or is the Network Admin section just a separation of options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they moved Super Admin menus and related pages out of the regular admin and into a new [Network Admin screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin).

and the updates are:

- Add contextual help for Network
  screens
- Add delete support to network themes
- Add plugin update notifications,
  plugin install, plugin update to the
  network admin screen
- Admin Bar similar to that used in wordpress.com blogs ([#14772](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14772))
- Move network version of Tools->Network to the network admin
- Move theme installer to the network admin for multisite installs
- Network Admin ([#14435](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14435))
- Network Wide Settings->Language Settings
- New Network Admins page for Theme enable/disable/upgrade
- Pass more information to notification filters
- Rename Update menu to Updates in network admin
- Revamp User-new.php including separate caps for adding users vs. creating users, allowing supes to add via email or username, split adding existing users and creating new users into separate forms
- Support wildcard domains in WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS and WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS
- Tabbed interface for site editing
- User Admin feature creates a separate "personal" dashboard to provide a single endpoint for accessing profile information, cross-site preferences, a launching point for accessing all of a user's blogs, collation of stats across all of a user's blogs, a place for a multisite aware quick press, etc. ([#14696](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14696))